# Convertir String a JSON

Tags: php, json

Tengo un Json que guarde en una base de datos pero cuando la extraigo no puedo regresarlo a objeto Json.

Primero Tengo un Objeto JSON que lo guardo asi:

```
<?php
$data= array( "nombre"=>"pedro", "edad"=>"10" );
$onJson= json_encode($data);

$q= "insert into PERSONAS(ID, DATO) values(\'10\', \'". $onJson. "\');";
mysql_query($q, $l);
?>
```

Después al extraerlo:

```
<?php
$q= "select * from PERSONAS where ID='10';";
mysql_query($q, $l);
$a= mysql_fetch_array($q);

echo "Esto es un String: ". $a["DATO"];
echo "\nAqui en JSON:\n";
print_r(json_encode($a["DATO"]));
?>
```

Pero no se convierte a objeto json :(

Comment: Hola, en `print_r(json_encode($a["DATO"]));` debería ser `print_r(json_decode($a["DATO"]));`

Answer (score 3):

Estás utilizando `json_encode` para el objeto que ya está codificado, para convertirlo a string debes utilizar `json_decode` por lo que tu código para extraer la información quedaría así:

```
<?php
$q= "select * from PERSONAS where ID='10';";
mysql_query($q, $l);
$a= mysql_fetch_array($q);

echo "Esto es un JSON: ". $a["DATO"];
echo "\nAqui en string:\n";
print_r(json_decode($a["DATO"]));
?>
```

Para entender mejor estas funciones te recomiendo leer un manual de PHP, te dejaré un enlace para que entiendas muy bien el `json_decode`.
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

1. si estas usando comillas dobles en la query de la variable $q no necesitas escapar las comillas simples con '\' (backslash), ni siquiera por estar usando json_encode.
2. si al ingresar los datos usas json_encode(), al leer los datos debes usar json_decode() en la columna correspondiente.

Ademas: te recomiendo que uses `json_decode($data['column'], true)` agregar 'true' como segundo parametro de json_decode() convertira el json en un array de PHP y no en un Object. para que cuando lo imprimas no te salga algo como ... stdClass sino Array ...

Comment: solo avisar que lo de añadir `true` al final de json_decode es para devolver array. En su caso es valido, porque en su proyecto esta trabajando con arrays, pero en caso de que codificara un objeto, lo suyo seria devolverlo como un stdClass. (vamos, solo especificar que la recomendacion es buena para su caso)